# What is the size of the structure in this code below assuming that we have structure padding and size of int is 4 and size of double is 8 bytes

Tags: c, structure, padding

Can anyone please tell me how come the size of the structure shown below is 24 and not 20.

```
typedef struct
{
    double d;  // this would be 8 bytes
    char c;   // This should be 4 bytes considering 3 bytes padding
    int a;   // This would be 4 bytes
    float b; // This would be 4 bytes
} abc_t;

main()
{
    abc_t temp;
    printf("The size of struct is %d\n",sizeof(temp));
}
```

My asumption is that the size of structure would be 20 when we consider padding but when i run this code the size is printing as 24.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1`, always. Not `4`. Padding and alignment does not affect the size of a member.

Comment: @Dai hence the `3 bytes padding` comment.

Comment: Yes it is 1 byte but including 3 bytes padding.

Comment: Isn't a struct padded to the width of its widest member, which is 8 bytes in this case?

Comment: What ISA did you build for? The alignment rules for x86 differ than x64 or ARM.

Comment: I am using DevC++

Comment: The *double* member still needs to be aligned when the struct is stored in an array.  That requires the struct to have a size that is a multiple of 8.  Padding is added at the end of the struct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size would be `24`. It is because **the last member is padded with the number of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment** of any structure member.

So padding would be like

```
typedef struct
{
    double d;  // This would be 8 bytes
    char c;    // This should be 4 bytes considering 3 bytes padding
    int a;     // This would be 4 bytes
    float b;   // Last member of structure. Largest alignment is 8.  
               // This would be 8 bytes to make the size multiple of 8 
} abc_t;
```

Read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) article for more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can i post another simple question to you?

Comment: a function pointer int (*fp)(int , int). When i print the size of fp, it is giving as 8 where i assume that any function pointer or a structure pointer would be 4 on a 32 bit machine.?

Comment: @user2520451; I am not quite sure. There is no guarantee that the size of both pointers can be same. Alignment of function pointer is different than that of structure pointers.

Comment: Section §6.2.5/28 of C11 draft says: *A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.*

Answer (score -1):

Maybe packed attribute will answer question.

```
typedef struct
{
    double d;  // this would be 8 bytes
    char c;   // This should be 4 bytes considering 3 bytes padding
    int a;   // This would be 4 bytes
    float b; // This would be 4 bytes
} __attribute__((packed)) abc_t ;
```

Comment: No, it does not correctly answer the question. Try it: is your sizeof now 20, as OP was expecting?

Comment: So I gave you the benefit of the doubt and tried. Result: `sizeof abc_t is 17`, which *is* correct for `packed` but not the `20` that OP expected.